# Check if $2$ rational maps are topologically conjugated in the complex plane.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Is there any way to know if the functions $f=\frac{z^2+6z+1}{3z^2+2z+3}$ and $g=\frac{2z^2+z+1}{3z+1}$ defined in $\mathbb{C}$ are topologically conjugated?

For me the definition of topological conjugation is: Let f : D → D and g : E → E 2 functions. We say
that they are topologically conjugated if there is a homomorphism φ : D → E, such that g(φ(z)) = φ(f (z)), ∀z ∈ D. In this case φ is called topological conjugation between f and g.

Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: As an interested reader, could you define what you mean by "topologically conjugated"?

Comment: I have just reformulated the statement to add the definition. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I do not know anything about complex analysis, but giving an explicit homomorphism (or homeomorphism?) seems pretty difficult. Maybe there are other arguments available for you, and you might want to check that first. Like looking at roots or other topological properties $f$ has, and $g$ does not have, which already shows that such $\varphi$ can not exist. Roots, singularities or other invariants.